# Why didn't I earn credits on replay of Starcraft 2 mission?

Tags: starcraft-2

I played Liberation Day and The Outlaws on brutal difficulty and completed the bonus objectives to get a total of 100,000 credits.

Then I completed Zero Hour on brutal but did not complete the bonus mission, so I did not get any credits.

I replayed Zero Hour on casual difficulty and completed the bonus objectives.  The game ended and told me I had earned 55,000 credits on the summary screen however back on Horner's Battle Cruiser, it says I still only have 100,000 credits.

Why do I not have 155,000 credits now?

Comment: I wasn't aware that completing the bonus objectives got you extra credits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No credits are earned by completing the bonus objectives.  Credits are earned for finishing the level.

- No credits are given for "Liberation Day."
- "The Outlaws" is worth 45,000 credits.
- "Zero Hour" is worth 55,000 credits.

When you finished these 3 games, it didn't matter whether you completed the bonus objectives or not.  You got 100,000 credits between the three after finishing them the first time.